# Docker issue Container ID 718322462 cannot be mapped to a host ID

Tags: docker, dockerfile, npm-install

Recently, our builds have started failing with the message:

> failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Container ID 718322462 cannot be mapped to a host ID

I figure out which part is failing,the files belong to the node_modules npm install for salesforce cli in base docker image with the high uid. However, the only existing issues I can find that sound similar are to do with multistage builds. The build is failing some time after the npm install in the base image in the following:

salesforce docker link - https://github.com/salesforcecli/sfdx-cli/blob/main/dockerfiles/Dockerfile_full

```
FROM  salesforce/salesforcedx:7.194.1-full

ARG AWS_CLI_VERSION=2.7.32
ARG SFPOWERSCRIPTS_VERSION=alpha

# Install Azure CLI and DevOps extension
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash && \
    az extension add --name azure-devops

# Install AWS CLI
RUN curl -sL "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && unzip awscliv2.zip && sudo ./aws/install

# install sfpowerscripts
RUN npm install --global @dxatscale/sfpowerscripts@$SFPOWERSCRIPTS_VERSION
```

Is there anything I can do if the issue is in the 3rd party docker image?